# package download fails , "GOPATH not set." why?

Tags: go

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Go version reporting: 1.1.1

Action:

I have configured the .profile to contain the following lines:

export GOPATH="$HOME/workspace"

export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

I have ensured that they are set in the go configuration by running "go env". However when I try to run the command, the screen reports as shown in the image below:

[image]

Possible constraining issues:

1) The box originally had Go v1.0 on it and I upgraded it to go version1.1.1, not sure that should mean anything...but if there is some twin configuration madness at work that may explain the fact it's not working despite the path being set.

2) I had the export commands in the .profile file but I see some threads indicate to put it in .bashrc, trying in either still gives the same problem.

Do I need to uninstall go 1.0 ? I just assumed version 1.1.1 would over ride it but that could be wrong. Ideally I wanted to uninstall go entirely and then install version 1.1.2 but I couldn't find anything at golang.org on uninstalling assuming that does solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You probably installed the package using `sudo` before which is why you're getting the permission denied error in the first place. Change the owner to your user and you should be fine. `sudo go get` won't work as with sudo there's a different environment and `GOPATH` won't be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commenter above stated, you should not use `sudo` with `go get`.  When you do, you have the root user's environment (which doesn't have your GOPATH) and any files or directories it creates won't be editable by your user.  In the past, the `go get` command would not warn about not having a `$GOPATH` and so it was easier to get tripped up by this.

To fix your permissions, run the following command to change ownership back to your user:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER:" "$GOPATH"
```

You should only ever need to run a plain `go get` because you can (and should) set your `$GOPATH` to be a directory you can control.  Be sure to read the [How To Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) and in particular its discusson on [GOPATH](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH).

Comment: Thank you Kyle, that worked straight away. Specifically I ran your command and then followed that with:

go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

:and it worked.